# How this YACC code makes a shift/reduce conflict?(very simple)

Tags: yacc

I really tried to understand why this makes a conflict but i think i'm missing something.

```
%token D
%start a

%%

a
    : b
    | a '+' b
    ;

b
    : c
    | c '+' '+'
    ;

c
    : D
    ;
```

I found out that same '+' characters are making the problem but i can't find any ambiguity in this code...

I really appreciate in advance

Comment: You should treat `++` as a single token in the lexer.

Comment: @user207421 thank you so much, but can I know the reason? Or is there no reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's label your alternatives as follows:

```
a
    : b          // a1
    | a '+' b    // a2
    ;

b
    : c          // b1
    | c '+' '+'  // b2
    ;
```

Now if the parser has just parsed a `c` and the next token is a `'+'`, there are two possibilities: The `+` could be part of `c '+' '+'`, in which case `b2` should be chosen, or the `+` could be part of `a '+' b`, in which case `b1` should be chosen and `a2` would be chosen next. However, the parser can't know which of these is the case without seeing the second `+` and YACC, being a `LALR(1)` parser generator, can only look one token ahead, not two.

So that's why you get a conflict. As has already been pointed out, the solution to this is to make `++` a single token. This also has the benefit that spaces are no longer allowed inside the `++`, which more closely matches the syntax of existing languages.